# Overhead in rxJava

Tags: java, performance, rx-java

I've been trying out rxJava in our code base, mostly looking to add concurrency boosting performance. However, there seems to be overhead/startup cost issues when I use rxJava. In the example below, in "doRx()" it takes ~130ms before getAllElements() is triggered, while in "doOld" it takes 0ms before getAllElements() is triggered. Any explanation to why I'm loosing 130ms initially in doRx()?

This is the logging I do, by using System.currentTimeMillis(). The () is elapsed time from init().

Existing implementation

- (0) 2016-10-11T13:34:07.060: OldImpl: init()
- (0) 2016-10-11T13:34:07.060: OldImpl: Call getAllElements()
- (327)    2016-10-11T13:34:07.387: OldImpl: Received getAllElements()

RX implementation

- (0) 2016-10-11T13:34:07.703: RxImpl: init()
- (**160**)    2016-10-11T13:34:07.863: RxImpl: Call
  getAllElements()
- (392)    2016-10-11T13:34:08.095: RxImpl:
  Received getAllElements()

The reasoning behind the code is that I first want to collect all elements, and then run them in parallel (under h2) since that is where we can save time as there are many backend invocations. I've used [this blog](http://tomstechnicalblog.blogspot.no/2015/11/rxjava-achieving-parallelization.html) as guidance for this setup.

```
public List<Element> doRx() {

    List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>();

    Observable
            .from(getAllElements())
            .flatMap(
                    s -> Observable
                            .just(Element::new)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                            .flatMap(
                                    e -> {

                                        List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>();

                                        for (SubElement se : e.getSubElements()) {

                                            elements.add(se);

                                        }

                                        return Observable.from(elements);
                                    }
                            )
            )
            .flatMap(

                    h1 -> Observable
                            .just(h1)
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
                            .flatMap(
                                    h2 -> {

                                        // Do additional things in parallell on all elements

                                        return Observable
                                                .just(h2);
                                    }
                            )
            )
            .toBlocking()
            .getIterator()
            .forEachRemaining(myList::add);

    return elements;
}


public List<Element> doOld() {

    List<Element> elements = getAllElements();

    for (Element e : elements) {
        // Do stuff, same as under h2   
    }

    return elements;
}
```

Comment: Did the old _sequential_ code use more than 1 thread?

Comment: No, just one thread. Sequential was a poor choice of word. Synchronous was what I meant. getElements() is the first step of the execution here.

Comment: You do realize h2 is a single threaded database?

Comment: @DaveMoten Might be. I've been trying a bit back and fourth, so maybe the code is not correct when it comes to the h2 being processed in parallel now. I have made the h2 part execute in parallel earlier so I am not concerned about that. If you have any general input to the code, I  appreciate it of course. However, is this relevant to my question? My issue here is that it takes 130ms before triggering getElements().

Comment: Could be the result of unbounded parallelism as you flatMap without maxConcurrency limit on the io() scheduler.

Comment: @akarnokd I've tried with computation() too. Retried now with Schedulers.from(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(50)). Same result.

Comment: So does `getElements()` itself take 130ms or getting all items from it takes 130ms? How fast does it run if you just have two nested for loops without concurrency.

Comment: @akarnokd It takes 130ms before getElements() is triggered. Everything after triggering of getElements() is fine, but I need to figure out what the 130ms in init time (where no execution happens) is.

Comment: What happens if you leave out all RxJava and just have `getElements()`?

Comment: @akarnokd That is what I referred to as "old, synchronous code". It takes 0ms to trigger getEkements().

Comment: Try with `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1)`. You could be overwhelming h2.

Comment: @akarnokd Tried it, did not change anything.

Comment: I still don't get it. If you have just `getElements()`, that goes by 0ms, if you have `getElements()` followed by an RxJava construct, that takes 130ms. Right? Can you use flight recorder to see where the time is spent?

Comment: @akarnokd  I havent tried flight recorder before. Will look into it. I updated the code to show the difference between the new rx solution and the (simplified) doOld()

Comment: Also, don't measure the time of the first invocation, but of the second (classes are loaded and thread pools are warmed-up).

Comment: @TassosBassoukos getElements() is called just once, and is the basis for later concurrency. As shown in doOld() where I do sync looping through the list of elements.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you code correctly, it's equivalent to the following:

```
public List<Element> doRx() {
    return Observable
        .from(getAllElements())
        .flatMap(element -> Observable
             .just(new Element(element))
             .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
             .flatMaplIterable(e -> e.getSubElements())
        )
        .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .doOnNext(element -> {
            // Do additional things in parallell on all elements
        })
        .toList()
        .toBlocking()
        .single();
}
```

This has at minimum 2 context switches per element more than the sequential version. How are you doing your timings? X runs, ignore biggest and smallest numbers?

Comment: Seems to be an equivalent, yes. Rewrite the my code to match this, and it worked, but no change in the timings.

Comment: I havent performed any thorough load test. I just have a simple test running this a few times. Ran it 15 times now, seems to be the same 100-150ms "lost" in the before calling getElements()

Comment: When you say "Ran", do you mean that you ran `java -jar ...` 15 times? Or does your code have `time(() -> doRx);` 15 time one after another?

Comment: Just a JUnit test calling the doRx() 15 times in sequence. Before each execution, get currentTimeMillis() to set start time of exection, and use same method to get elapsed time on different points in the code